# Automatically rollback transaction on try catch construction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, try-catch, rollback

I'm using the `try catch` construction like

```
try {
    foo();
    bar();
} catch(SomeException $exception){
    throw new SomeException('some exception');
}


foo()
{
    // sql query 'INSERT INTO .... execute query
}

bar() 
{
    try{
        //some logic
    } catch(SomeException2 $exception){
        throw new SomeException2('some exception2');
    }
}
```

Case 1:

When executing the bar() method I get an exception 'SomeException2' and record in MYSQL table is rolled back like as if I used a transaction rollback

If i try...

Case2

```
try {
    db->startTransaction();
    foo();
    db->commitTransaction();
    bar();
} catch(SomeException $exception){
  
    throw new SomeException('some exception');
}
```

my record is saving in database.

Does `catch` rollback the transaction in Case #1?

Comment: A transaction is executed completely when there was no rollback and the transaction was ended. Once commited, the transaction is complete. When the connection was closed before nothing should have been written.

Comment: The transaction is not rolled back, it is just left open. Probably at some point it will be garbage-collected. Just roll it back yourself. BTW: Catching an exception and just throwing a different one is an antipattern, which makes me wonder what your code really looks like. BTW2: Use an abstraction layer ("ORM") instead of writing raw queries. This will also give you guidance concerning transactions. At the very least, study an ORM, e.g. "cakephp/database".

Comment: @MarkusZeller Hello! thanks for the comment! But I didn't realize "commit"&"rollback" in case#1. What does a rollback/commit do - php or mysql?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried it and in the first case, when there was an exception, the row in the database was not created. As if there was a rollback (Although I didn't describe the rollback)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt hello! Thanks for recommendations. I use ORM in my project. Here I described it simply schematically block of code :) 
Оk, the transaction has opened... Why did she commit if the execution didn’t fail? Is this control on MYSQL or PHP side?

Comment: Read some basics about how transactions work here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php